# How can align text in a center in left position?

Tags: html, css

I have this sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/3gmeK/298/

**CSS and HTML:**

```css
div   { padding:10px 20px; background-color:#F51; }

p     { text-align:left; padding:5px; background-color:#333; color:#fefefe; }
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    There are many fish in the sea! So lovely!<br>
    many fish in the sea! So lovely!
  </p>
</div>
```

I want my text in its current form is aligned in the center.

I do not want to use `"text-align: center;"`

Inside this div my text means to be in current form.

I hope I managed to explain better what they want to do.You can help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/k8j7yehs/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3gmeK/300/

Comment: Am image of what this is supposed to look like would be helpful but `text-align:center` on the **parent** and `inline-block` on the `p` would center the paragraph (but not the text **in** the `p` but obviously the bg color would "collapse" - http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/3gmeK/302/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by adding an extra `span` around the text:

- Add `text-align: center;` to `p`
- Add an extra `span` around the text
- Add a new `span` selector with `display: inline-block;` to make the `span` center in relation to the `p` and `text-align: left;` to shift it's text to the left

```css
div {
  background-color: #F51;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
p {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fefefe;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <span>There are many fish in the sea! So lovely!<br>
            many fish in the sea! So lovely!</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this,

Add `<span>` tag for content and add this css

```
p span{ display: table;margin:auto;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3gmeK/304/