# Aligning text differently based on whether it is multiline?

Tags: css, text-align

I'm looking for a CSS solution to align text differently based on whether it breaks into more than one line or not. No Javascript, thanks. I'm happy with edge browser support, though.

Here's what I want to achieve:

[image]

When the text content only fills one line, I want it to adhere to `text-align: center;`. Else, I'd like it to be `text-align: left`.

I'm aware that I could assign different classes based using Javascript based on:

- number of characters
- height of element vs line-height

But these solutions aren't generic and have many complications. What I'm looking for is a CSS (probably CSS3 edge) solution to the problem that has so-far eluded me.

Comment: Curious about a use-case for this!

Comment: My answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663489/how-can-align-text-in-a-center-in-left-position/30663603#30663603 would sort of do what you want, as long as the text is one long sentence _without_ line breaks. It would require an extra element to be added to the markup.

Comment: @George I feared as much. Just wanted to double check there wasn't some spec'd edge CSS3 on the horizon that I had missed.

Comment: @Paulie_D The reasons are aesthetic; as per the implied term *style* in 'cascading style sheet'. Dare I say, it sounds a little unimaginative to equate aesthetic preferences to worthy/unworthy 'use cases'. :-)

Comment: @George For sure there is a CSS-only solution. Check mine

Comment: @George check my update pls. It is possible with a single element, if background is not required.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a pure CSS solution:

```css
div {
   background-color: yellow;
   width: 200px;
}
  
div span {
   display: inline-block;     
   position: relative;
   left: 50%;       /* move content to the right until the left side is aligned to the middle of the div container (at 100px)  */
   -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%); /* move half of content's width back to the left. This centers content.*/ 
   -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
   transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>this is a single line content</span>
</div>
<br />
<div>
  <span>this is a single line</span>
</div>
<hr />
<div>
  <span>this is an example of multi line content</span>
</div>
<br />
<div>
  <span>this is an example of very long multi line content that occupies three rows</span>
</div>
```

By putting your content in an `inline-block` you get the width of such content restrained inside the div container.

---

If you cannot add an extra element (`span`) to your markup, it is still possible to do what you want with just divs, with

```
div {
  background-color: yellow;
  max-width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

However the yellow background only covers the content area, not the 200px. I've tried using pseudo elements `:before` to no avail.

Comment: A very interesting technique. Bravo. One gripe I have with it is its' current need to break the natural behaviour of the `<span>` element. For my personal use, I would rather target a wrapper `<div>`  with the suggested CSS and allow any possible child `<span>` elements to work as expected.

Comment: I've adapted this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0g5vtuyr/) for when you need to honour `<span>` child elements.

Comment: @Jose Rui Santos, I think I may have a way of getting the background working on the single `div` solution. Would you be happy for me to post a new answer based upon your existing code?

Comment: @HiddenHobbes the background is unimportant to the specifics of the question, in my opinion. This is about text alignment, not background colour. The background colour was used as a means to show the boundaries of the parent element.

Comment: @shennan Fair enough, if the consensus is that it isn't needed there seems little point me adding a new answer. :)